# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'class'

Tags: java, eclipse, debian-9

Estoy abriendo un proyecto en linux con IDE eclipse que originalmente fue creado en windows, con netbeans y corría perfectamente.

Ahora me aparecen dos errores:

1. Me dirige al `persistence.xml`. Sale este error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'class'. One of
>   '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.

2. Me dirige a `faces-config.xml`:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'managed-bean'. One of
>   '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":action-listener,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":default-render-kit-id,
>   "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":message-bundle, }' is expected.

Estes es mi `Persistence`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="sisgriPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.CruceClienteLista</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.Menu</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ListaIdRestriccion</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.Usuario</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ArchivoFuente</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.Catalogo</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ListaCatalogo</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ListaRestriccion</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ArchivoClienteMasivo</class>
    <class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.model.ClienteMasivo</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxx"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxx"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxx/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Y este es mi `faces-config`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

    <application>
        <message-bundle>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.properties.mensajes</message-bundle>

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>es</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.properties.mensajes</base-name>
            <var>msj</var>
        </resource-bundle>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>autenticacionController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.AutenticacionController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>plantillaConMenuController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.PlantillaConMenuController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>cargaArchivoController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.cargaFuentes.CargaArchivoController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>consultaListaController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.consultaListas.ConsultaListaController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>cargaArchivoClienteController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.cargaFuentes.CargaArchivoClienteController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>consultaListaMasivoController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.consultaListas.ConsultaListaMasivoController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

        <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>gestionUsuarioController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.leonsoftware.amlgestionriesgo.controller.gestionUsuario.GestionUsuarioController</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
        </managed-bean>

    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio por la edición de la pregunta, por otra parte el primer error ya logré solucionarlo, cambie el persistence subiendo los class  que estan despues de <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> y los coloque antes, y desaparecio el error ^^

Comment: Paulo, le recomiendo colocar su comentario como una respuesta *ya que soluciona uno de los dos problemas que colocó*. Cuando encuentre la segunda solución, siempre podrá actualizar la respuesta. Espero que otras personas le puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El primer error ya logré solucionarlo: cambié el `persistence` subiendo los `class` que están después de esta línea:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

y los coloqué antes, y desapareció el error.

Answer (score -1):

El segundo error en el faces-config, fue colocar todos los `<managed-bean>` antes del `<application>`.

Comment: Agrega actualizaciones a tu pregunta mediante el enlace [editar] , te recomiendo eliminar esta publicación. para realizar respuestas en el sitio revisa [answer], saludos!